# What is the cleanest way of finding the indices of all entries in a numpy array that matches a pattern?

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

Is there a way to neatly extract the indices of all values in an array that matches a pattern?

The following example produces a list of tuples with indices matching the elements of the array A that are True

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[False, False, False, True],
              [False, True, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False]])
indices = list()
for i, K in enumerate(A):
    for j, L in enumerate(K):
        if L:
            indices.append((i, j))
```

This works, but it seems ugly and 'unpythonic'. A specific flaw in this solution is that it relies on the dimentionality of A. Is there a better way? It doesn't matter if the indices are produced as a list of tuples or something else that is easily accessible.

Comment: I think `np.where(A == value)` is standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `np.argwhere`:

```
In [1]: A = np.array([[False, False, False, True],
   ...:               [False, True, False, False],
   ...:               [False, False, False, False]])

In [2]: np.argwhere(A == True)
Out[2]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 1]])
```